# asp.net GetStringAsync sometimes returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to retrieve flight data from a large JSON file which sometimes takes longer than 1 minute and comes from a different streaming source, the final file size is around 10mg+. The below code works but if the API takes a long time I get Null in the response, although I have tested the same in PostMan and did not get null. Am I doing anything wrong with my code? is there a way where I can read the data as it comes as the data does not come all at once?

This is the method I have in my controller:

```
 private async Task<List<Model>> GetFlightData()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=" + flightSearchID);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(content);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Returned JSON:

[image: Making the request in Chrome]

Comment: If i'm not mistaken HttpClient has a default of 100s while asp.net webapi has a total request default of 110s.

Comment: set request timemout to -1 .

Comment: Thank you Orel And AF, I added client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite); and Its better now.                                Is it possible to show the search results not in full (as it comes), meaning I show them one by one in the process of receiving response from API?